# Unable to send get request with headers using axios

Tags: javascript, api, react-native, axios

Able to get the response in `postman`. But unable to get in `axios`. Getting html as response. What would be the problem?

```
import axios from 'react-native-axios';

var config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
    'JsonStub-User-Key': '__USER__KEY',
    'JsonStub-Project-Key': '__PROJECT__KEY'
  }
};

export async function menuListByCategories() {
  // simulate an asynchronous operation
  const url = "http://jsonstub.com/burgers";
  axios.get(url, {config})
    .then((response) = > {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .
  catch ((error) = > {
    console.log("axios error:", error);
  });
}
```

**Update:** [check the response of this code](http://prntscr.com/h6h0td)

Comment: Do you get any error response like 404, 500 or something like that?

Comment: @IzumiSy getting 200 as response. and its in html format. Not in json

Comment: But you cannot get 200 response with axios, right? Then, what do you get?

Comment: check the SS of the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data: {}` in `config` in order not to have `Content-Type` removed by axios. Check the answer of the question below.

[Jsonstub response not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981640/jsonstub-response-not-showing)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Tried but not working. we can't set data for a GET request, and at the same time, the "Content-Type" header for a request without data gets ignored.  How can I handle?

Comment: How about changing `{config}` just to `config` and trying it again?

Comment: Ya. If I change into that, I get status as 403.

Comment: You are getting one step closer. 403 means "Forbidden" so that I think your API keys might not correct to call API. Could you check them out?

Comment: creds are correct. I'm getting JSON data in postman. If I use {config}, then status is 200 OK and its in html response. I want it in json. But unable to get it.

Comment: That's not a correct. Do you really have a correct API keys? Invalid API keys causes you to get 403. I created a working one which returns with JSON: https://runkit.com/izumisy/59ff3c6d81a8a80011b3a073

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158265/discussion-between-balasubramanian-and-izumisy).

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. Got the response.